# set domain in pgfplots

Tags: graphics, pgfplots

I created this graph. The graph is shown correctly but I need the range on the y-axis to be from 10e-8 to 1. I would also like a grid. I'm a newbie with the `pgfplots` package.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[xlabel=distanza]
\addplot [domain=0.0000001:1,
          thick,blue]
    file {./MATLAB/file.txt};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `ymin=`, `ymax=` to define the y-axis limits (everything outside of the axis limits will be clipped away). For the grid, you have the `grid=` option; a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[ymin=0.000000001,ymax=1,xlabel=distanza,grid=major]
\addplot [thick,blue]
    coordinates {(1,0.0000001) (2,0.0065) (3,0.1) (4,0.9)};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it exist a way to get a plot bigger?

Comment: @Mazzy you can specify a width using, for example `width=13cm`, as an option to the `semilogyaxis`as in `\begin{semilogyaxis[ymin=0.000000001,ymax=1,xlabel=distanza,grid=major,width=12cm]` or globally, using something like `\pgfplotsset{width=10cm}` in the preamble.

Comment: Great fantastic...you are so nice...Thank you

Comment: I posted a new discussion.maybe you could help me.... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86631/create-scatter-plot-from-dat-file

Comment: @Mazzy I was having dinner, but I see you have already received an answer :-)