# create scatter plot from dat file

Tags: pgfplots

I would create a scatter plot using pgfplots using data from my dat file that contains this data:

```
nodes     x         y       label

1.0000    14.1209   7.0332  a

2.0000     0.6367   16.6166 a

3.0000     5.5385   11.7053 a

4.0000     0.9234   10.9945 a

5.0000     1.9426   18.3439 b

6.0000    16.4692    5.7168 b

7.0000    13.8966   15.1440 a

8.0000     6.3420   15.0746 a

9.0000    19.0044    7.6089 b

10.0000    0.6889   11.3564 b
```

I would create a scatter plot where the first column is the label of every scatter while the two next colomn are x and y. The last column is a class that decide if the scatter has to be red or blue
This is the code I had created

```
 \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=metri,ylabel=metri]
        \addplot[nodes near coords*={\thisrow{nodes}},
            scatter/classes={
                a={mark=*,blue},
                b={mark=*,red}
                },
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic]
         table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]
            {./MATLAB/grafici/network_map.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately in this way I don't get the label. Something doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using meta info for colors, you need to use `visualization depends on` for the remaining data. And it should come after the `scatter src` option otherwise it will be overwritten.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
nodes     x         y       label
1.0000    14.1209   7.0332  a
2.0000     0.6367   16.6166 a
3.0000     5.5385   11.7053 a
4.0000     0.9234   10.9945 a
5.0000     1.9426   18.3439 b
6.0000    16.4692    5.7168 b
7.0000    13.8966   15.1440 a
8.0000     6.3420   15.0746 a
9.0000    19.0044    7.6089 b
10.0000    0.6889   11.3564 b
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=metri,ylabel=metri]
        \addplot[
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{nodes}\as\myvalue},
            scatter/classes={
                a={mark=*,blue},
                b={mark=*,red}
                },
                scatter, only marks,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                nodes near coords*={\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]\myvalue},]
         table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]
            {mydata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it exist a way to get label smaller?

Comment: @Mazzy You can add `\tiny` or `\small` before the `\pgfmathprintnumber`